# An Infinite Dimensional Vector Space Question

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Let $V$ denote the vector space which is the span of the set
$$
S=\left\{\mathrm{e}^{\lambda x}|\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.
$$
Prove that $V$ does not have finite dimension.

I tried to start the question to show that $S$ is a linearly independent set if any finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent. But I still failed to do so..

Could somebody help me with this question please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k e^{\lambda_k x} = 0$ for all $x$, where the $\lambda_k$ are distinct, and since they are real, we can assume that
$\lambda_1 < \cdots < \lambda_n$. Note that $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-\lambda_n x} f(x)= \alpha_n$, from which we get $\alpha_n = 0$. Repeating for the other $\lambda_k$ gives $\alpha_k = 0$ also. Hence they are linearly independent.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot :) Now how to continue to show that $V$ does not have finite dimension? We know now $S$ is a basis, but the point is can we apply the Basis Theorem here?

Comment: If $V$ had finite dimension, then there would be a finite spanning set $\Sigma \subset S$. Then any element of $S\setminus \Sigma$ could be written in terms of the linear span of $\Sigma$, which would contradict the above...

Comment: Alternatively, the above shows that $\{ x \mapsto e^{k x} \}_{k=1}^n$ is linearly independent for all $n$, hence $\dim V \ge n$ for all $n$, hence infinite.

Comment: Ah yes that makes a lot of sense now! Thanks so much:)

Comment: Glad to be able to help...

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and choose distinct $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Then $\{e^{\lambda_i x}\,|\,i=1,\ldots n\}$ is independent. This can be shown as follows: if 
$\sum_j a_j e^{\lambda_j x}=0$ for some nontrivial coefficients $a_j$, then the same equation holds for the first, second, $\ldots$, $(n-1)$st derivatives. If you evaluate everything in $0$, you get a contradiction, because no nontrivial linear combination of $(1, \lambda_i,\ldots, \lambda_i^{n-1})$ is zero (because the [Vandermonde determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) is nonzero).